# Open Facebook managed page always gives "Network error"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-apps

I'm directing users from my app to my Facebook app on the Mobile/Web with those lines:

```
try {
    EventParams("type", "follow_facebook"));

     /* should work after adding keyhash to the android app */

     context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
   ((Activity) context).startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/"
                    + FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
            ((Activity) context).startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.facebook.com/zyggabar")));
    }
```

The facebook app indeed loaded but always with "Network error" title. I'm guessing that this is a Facebook bug. Does anyone encountered in this type of facebook behavior?